# How to add breadcrumbs in product category and product details page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, breadcrumbs

I have added the following code to the following file.

> **app/design/frontend/Emthemes/everything/diamond/Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml**

```
<move element="breadcrumbs" destination="content" before="-" />
```

But it's not working for me.
Anyone can help me regarding this.

Comment: breadcrumbs already displayed by default on those pages.

Comment: No its not showing on my project so i have added in default.xml

Answer (score 1):

as @Suresh Chikani mentioned in the comment, breadcrumbs are displayed OOTB in those places(product page & category), if it's not then somebody removed it.

It could be removed in few ways

1) somebody removed the parent block in which the block containing your   functionality was, in this case just "move" the block containing your desired functionality to a different existing block/container

2) somebody removed the block, you need to find the code and change it or add a new block as you done in your answer.

3) Somebody could rewrite the block class (Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs) itself and override the toHtml function or any other that is responsible for displaying content. 
Look in

```
di.xml
```

for

```
Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs
```

if nothing is found then no one rewritten it.

4) Somebody could rewritten

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

Where the setup of breadcrumbs originally takes place.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

And going back to your question, if you want only add it only category &  product page then you should add it to

```
catalog_product_view.xml
catalog_category_view.xml
```

not to default.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to display breadcrumbs on list or detail page

```
<move element="breadcrumbs" destination="page.top"  />
```

Comment: Hi Suresh thanks for your response let's me check and revert

Comment: Okay check it from your and let me know if not working.

Comment: No bro its not working for me

Comment: I have added this code and also run cache clean and flush command

Comment: Please find breadcrumbs keyword and check in your theme and module, I think in somewhere remove breadcrumbs from layout.

Comment: I have checked it from catalog folder and also theme folder its not remove..

Comment: have you used custom theme?

Comment: yes i am using custom code..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80588/discussion-between-er-sarvesh-v-tiwari-and-suresh-chikani).

Answer (score 0):

**Added the following code to this path:**

> *app/design/frontend/Emthemes/everything/diamond/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml*

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
        </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Is this even working ? I mean, the pattern for design is usually 
app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME(2lvls) and you  instead of that have an extra level  (3rd) 
Your code adds it to all pages, not only to the  category   & product page, anyway breadcrumbs are OOTB